What's the influence of the filter roll-off on the delta-sigma modulator?

Understanding Delta-Sigma Data Converters, 2nd edition

Different filters with different roll-off slopes and stop-band rejections, how do they influence the delta-sigma modulator?
Would the roll-off and the stop-band rejection determine the dynamic range?

user71925 - Hi, Where did those images come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each item. If an original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) please [edit] the question & add its name & link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If an original source is a printed book or other offline material, please see the linked rule for details. || Please see the [tour] & [help], if you haven't already, as site rules here differ from typical forums.

Thanks, already edited.

user71925 - Thanks for adding a book name. A few things are still unclear, can you please clarify: Are both images from that same book? If not, where does the other one come from? What page in the book does/do the image/s come from? TY
